# Descending dungeons of positional systems

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

The sequence discussed in this challenge is a variant of the Descending Dungeons sequence family. Specifically, the sequence generation rules:

```
(A_b = A's base 10 representation read as a base b number, A = A_10)
A(0) = 10
A(n) = 10_(11_(12_(...(n+9)_(n+10))))
```

Your goal is to make a program which accepts a nonnegative integer `n` and returns A(n) of the descending dungeons sequence, using 0-indexing.

Base conversion built-ins are allowed.

Return the result itself in base 10.

Test cases: (`A = B` means `input A returns B`)

```
0 = 10
1 = 11
2 = 13
3 = 16
4 = 20
5 = 25
6 = 31
7 = 38
8 = 46
9 = 55
10 = 65
11 = 87
12 = 135
13 = 239
14 = 463
15 = 943
16 = 1967
17 = 4143
18 = 8751
19 = 18479
20 = 38959
```

Use OEIS [A121263](http://oeis.org/A121263) for further test cases.

This is code golf, so the shortest program wins. Have fun.

Final sidenote: This sequence came to my attention through a recent [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNx3JxRhnZE) discussing descending dungeon sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÝT+.«ö
```

Basically a golfed version of [*@hi.*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209298/52210), which I suggested as a golf in the comments of his/her answer. Since I got no response, I figured I'd just post it myself instead.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NwQbb1Dqw9v@//fDAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kcGySn72SwqO2SQpK9n7/D88N0dY7tPrwtv86/wE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý       # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input-integer]
 T+     # Add 10 to each value in this list
   .«   # Right-reduce this list by:
     ö  #  Base-conversion
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[You can replace the `.` with `Å` to see each step of the reduction (from right to left).](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NwQ7cOth1Yf3vb/vxkA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ż+⁵ṚDḅ¥@/
```

A monadic Link accepting a non-negative integer which yields a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//xbsr4oG14bmaROG4hcKlQC////8yMA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//xbsr4oG14bmaROG4hcKlQC//xbzDh@KCrEf//3JhbmdlKDIxKQ).

#### How?

```
Ż+⁵ṚDḅ¥@/                  e.g. 5
Ż         - zero-range          [0,1,2,3,4,5]
  ⁵       - ten                 10
 +        - add                 [10,11,12,13,14,15]
   Ṛ      - reverse             [15,14,13,12,11,10]
        / - reduce by:          f(f(f(f(f(15,14),13),12),11),10)
       @  -   using swapped arguments:         e.g. f(y=15,x=14)
      ɗ   -     last two links as a dyad
    D     -       decimal (x)                       [1,4]            
     ḅ    -       convert (that) from base (y)      19
                           i.e. f(f(f(f(f(15,14),13),12),11),10)
                              = f(f(f(f(19,13),12),11),10)
                              = f(f(f(22,12),11),10)
                              = f(f(24,11),10)
                              = f(25,10)
                              = 25
```

Comment: @Arnauld thanks, was just the final evaluation that had an error at f(22,12)=24 (where I gave 26 :/)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>75</s> 72 bytes

```python
f,g=lambda n:n and f(n-1)+n*g(n)or 10,lambda n:n and(n+9)//10*g(n-1)or 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczBCoMwEIThe59i8bRbIyYIBQX7LpE06YIdJXjx6dN4dA7/6WP28/huGEqJJs2r/y3BEyaQR6DI6Jy0eCaGbJmcNXfBaEfpe2cvUellSqxVUlD2SB9@jTI9qG7PioPVUNO9G1PPVaT8AQ)

Explanation: On observing the terms, I came across this recursive relation

`f(n) = f(n-1) + n*g(n)` where `g(n)` is the product of first `n` terms of the sequence

`1^1, 1^2, ... 1^10, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, ... 2^10, 3^1, 3^2, 3^3 ...`

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n<2and n+10or(f(n-1)-f(n-2))*n//~-n*((n+9)//10)+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDoIwEEbhvaeYsJqhNKVlJUHvUgLVSfQvadiw4epV49t8m7cd@zNjqDXdXvE9L5EwYgoRC8H4PhdODOvF/ggiLZw7LVpmmKs453sx/6OmXEhJQSXisXIYZLzQt60odtaOGntvOkqsIvUD)

Explanation: This is an even more recursive approach of the above solution, with the `g` function completely removed. However note that this one is highly inefficient.

`f(n) = f(n-1) + n*g(n)` implies `g(n-1) = (f(n-1) - f(n-2))/(n-1)`

---

*Special thanks to Jo King for -4 bytes.*

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

```javascript
n=>(F=i=>(g=k=>i>n?k:k&&k%10+F(i)*g(k/10|0))(++i+9))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDoIwEIDhnae4AcmdjVrcFK9uPEcJUlJLrgaMS@XZKy5/vuF/dp9u6Wf/eh8kPobsOAsbbNlvHTmw8Ubu4RqqKuxqrVr0tB8xnGr91USolFcXImuzizMKMOgGBG4M5z@UIkgFQB9lidNwnOKItsMyyUrbWyaHQqulpljzDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                // n = input
  F = i => (          // F is a recursive function taking a counter i
    g = k =>          //   g is a recursive function taking a number k
                      //   and returning either k if i > n or k converted
                      //   from base F(i) to decimal otherwise
      i > n ?         //     if i is greater than n:
        k             //       just return k
      :               //     else:
        k &&          //       return 0 if k = 0
        k % 10 +      //       otherwise extract the last digit of k
        F(i) *        //       and add F(i) multiplied by the result of
        g(k / 10 | 0) //       a recursive call with floor(k / 10)
  )(++i + 9)          //   increment i; initial call to g with k = i + 9
)``                   // initial call to F with i zero'ish
```

Comment: JS lambdas are terse, huh!

Comment: When I saw your answer, I thought that Markdown in this answer wasn't working...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>110</s> <s>107</s> <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 90 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,b=10:f(n-1,sum((int(v)*b**i)for i,v in enumerate(str(10+n)[::-1])))if n+1else b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsIwEEDRvacYuppJE2gQBAP1IuIiwUQH2mlJ0oKnj9a/f3/91Pci59bSOPk5PD2IDqMdXEIxVpdtRmSpuJMKSjGlJQPrHVggyjbH7GvEUjPaoRe6O2fsg4g4gfQ2TiVCaH9ziOzlFfFyJXeCX2s@zqyhM7dOQ0Imal8)

Uses recursion to compute the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that the default rules allow you to have a second parameter.

Comment: @Neil thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
.UijZTb}+TQT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy80MysqJKlWOyQw5P9/I4N/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

### Explanation

```
.UijZTb}+TQT
       }+TQT  # inclusive range [10 + input, 10]
.U            # reduce left to right by: f(b, Z)
   jZT        #   list of Z  (e.g. 123 -> [1, 2, 3])
  i   b       #   convert that from base b
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>105</s>...<s>57</s> 50 bytes

```
n=>((10 to n+10):\10)((i,r)=>(0/:s"$i")(_*r+_-48))
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fRLhUlcYQ0qBIFJIgN9ODQ)

Well, this has been a fun problem.

Explanation:

```
n =>
    ((10 to n+10) //A range from 10 to n+10
      :\10) (     //Fold it right with the initial value of 10
      (i, r) =>      //r is the current base, i is the counter
        (0 /: s"$i") //Make i a string/iterable of chars, and fold it left with an initial value of 0
           (_*r + _-48) //Multiply the previous value by r and add the current value to that (-48 because it's a Char and not a proper Int)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁺θχηＦθ≔⍘Ｉ⁻⁺θ⁹ιηηＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLsbg4Mz1PIyCntFijUEfB0EBTRyEDKJ6WX6QAVKAAlXdKLE4NLinKzEvXcE4sLtHwzcwDaoDpsgRqytQE64ToDgCqLIGozNDUtP7/39Dov25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔⁺θχη
```

Start with `n+10`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop `n` times.

```
≔⍘Ｉ⁻⁺θ⁹ιηη
```

Cast the previous integer to string and interpret it using the current base.

```
Ｉη
```

Print the final value as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 88 bytes

```
.+
10$*@$&$*;
(?!@)
$.`
\d+$
$*#
{`#(?=#*\d*;(#+)$)
$1
(\d)(\d*;#+)$
$1$*#$2
}`#;#+$
#
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc27CsJAFEXRfv@F3KvMA0JuHj4IknT@xBQjxMLGQuzEbx8n7doHzvvxeb7uZe9uuTQRazUsetAw4ebd4tEmk9aoaBC@Wdx8lZDWMDmJXms3XFq922iTCnWpHb8sFRRBSmkxOnoGRo6cOHOpV5hhHdZjAzb@AQ) Link includes some test cases (code gets too slow for TIO with larger numbers). Explanation:

```
.+
10$*@$&$*;
```

Convert the input to `n` `;`s, and prepend with 10 `@`s.

```
(?!@)
$.`
```

Insert the decimal numbers `10..n+10` around the `;`s.

```
\d+$
$*#
```

Convert the last number to unary using `#`s.

```
{`
}`
```

Reduce right-to-left over the list of numbers and left-to-right over the digits of each number.

```
#(?=#*\d*;(#+)$)
$1
```

Multiply the partial result so far by the base.

```
(\d)(\d*;#+)$
$1$*#$2
```

Add the next digit of the number to convert.

```
#;#+$
#
```

Once the number has been converted, delete the previous base, so that this result can serve as the base for the next conversion.

```
#
```

Once all of the numbers have been converted, convert the result to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 101 bytes

```
method(x,Range 10 to(x+10)asList reverseReduce(i,j,j asString asList map(asNumber)reduce(x,y,x*i+y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxDsIgEIDhvU9xI2cZqKOJb2Ac6uqC7dHSCDQHNfTpkVj/@c9nQzFwucKzOEpzGEWWvfYTQacgBZHbTqGONxsTMH2II/U0bgMJKxe5gI6PxNZP8H@cXoWO9829iJGPM8td5pNtd0QsB/6zzwrBBCY9zFVroGaERVgrmN6@wfIF)

### Explanation

```
method(x,                // Take an argument x
    Range 10 to(x+10)    // [10..x+10]
    asList               // Reduce doesn't work on ranges
    reverseReduce(i,j,   // Reverse the list. Reduce (arguments i & j):

                         //     tl;dr base conversion from j (base 10) to base i
        j asString       //     Convert to string,
        asList           //     Convert to list,   (splits string into individual chars)
        map(asNumber)    //     (Map) Convert to number.
        reduce(x,y,      //     Reduce the digit list by (arguments x & y):
            x*i+y)))     //          x*i+y
```

Comment: @DLosc No, you can't do that. The starting value of a range has to be a constant integer, you can't afford to have variables in them. [Try it!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQicoMS89VUGjQtvQQFOhJF8DSGn@hwgagPhGQOG0/KLUxOQMjUwdLgUgSNPI1FQoKMrMK8nJ49L8DwA "Io – Try It Online")

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I got that `Range does not respond to 'to'` exception and thought I must be doing something wrong with the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>71</s> 62 bytes

*Edits: +3 bytes to fix output for edge-case of n=0, but then -12 bytes by skipping calculation of number of digits each step and simply calculating over an excessively large number of digits)*

```r
n=i=scan()+10;while((i=i-1)>10)n=sum(i%/%10^(m=i:0)%%10*n^m);n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoBACADA1whaRNqxxZ6ysESQkB5aoudbc5o7M9S07y2QRuHynnYdiKY2CW3CFNofR4MZhCu62soE/4eoTiVy4fwA)

Readable (un-golfed) version:

```r
n=i=scan()+10               # get n and add 10; set i to same value as n
'%_%'=function(a,b)         # Define infix _ function 
                            # (this is incorporated directly inline in golfed code):
    m=rev(0:log10(a))       #   m = exponents-of-ten for each digit of a
                            #   (in golfed code we use m=a:0 which is much shorter
                            #   but uselessly includes exponentially more digits, 
                            #   which will all contribute zero to the final sum)    
    sum(                    #   get sum of... 
        a %/% 10^m %% 10    #   each base-10 digit of a...
        * b^m )             #   multiplied by corresponding exponent-of-b.
while((i=i-1)>10)           # Main loop from (n-1)..10:
    n = i %_% n             #   n = i _ n
n                           # Output n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> <s>21</s> 18 bytes

- *Saved 4 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*
- *Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)*

```apl
(⊢⊥10⊥⍣¯1⊣)/9+⍳⎕+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdoeC/xqOuRY@6lhoaAIlHvYsPrTd81LVYU99S@1Hv5kd9U7UNQer@K4BBAZcBF4xlCGcZwVnGcJYJnGUKZ5nBWeZwlgWcZYkwGckShC2GCGsMEfYYIiwyRNhkiLDKEGGXIcIyQ4RtRgYA)

Accepts input through STDIN.

```apl
(⊢⊥10⊥⍣¯1⊣)/9+⍳⎕+1
             9+⍳⎕+1  ⍝ Create a range from 10 to n+10
            /        ⍝ Then fold over it with the train on the left:
   10(⊥⍣¯1)          ⍝ Get the digits of (inverse of interpreting in base 10)
           ⊣         ⍝ A (the number on the left).
 ⊥                   ⍝ Interpret in base
⊢                    ⍝ b (the accumulated value on the right)
```

Comment: Based on the [APLcart](https://aplcart.info/) entry for *Digits of N*, the inner *dfn* can be shortened to `{⍵⊥10(⊥⍣¯1)⍺}`. And by converting the outer *dfn* to a train another byte can be saved: https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZHXUsNDTSA5KPexYfWG2o@6t1Vq2@p/ahjxqPezYbaj7oW/U971DbhUW/fo67mR71rHvVuObTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdn8P@0Qys0gBqMDDV1DQE

Comment: @ovs That's really nice, thanks!

Comment: Full program, 18: `(⊢⊥10⊥⍣¯1⊣)/9+⍳⎕+1` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKNdoeC/xqOuRY@6lhoaAIlHvYsPrTd81LVYU99S@1Hv5kd9U7UNQer@K4BBAZcBF4xlCGcZwVnGcJYJnGUKZ5nBWeZwlgWcZYkwGckShC2GCGsMEfYYIiwyRNhkiLDKEGGXIcIyQ4RtRgYA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: Any reason [you only requested](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/43319) 50 rep for this?

Comment: @Adám Thanks! (Sorry, I didn't notice your first comment earlier)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 72 bytes

```
.+
*
L$`
0;$.($`10*
$
¶10
{+`\d+;(\d)(\d*¶(\d+))$
$.(*$3*_$1*);$2
;¶.+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy7CcMwGAb7m@MPWBIYffIbDZAmIxiigFOkSRHSZS8P4MUcFXfVcZ/n9/V@6Lw013K2Ac/NCjFb21hR9BjHrsgvlHULuVk3V/HHXh2cM2rorfN3k3fZEvnY22CcZ0QkOnoGRiZmFupIQgl1qEcDGtGEZrSQ4h8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
L$`
0;$.($`10*
```

For each integer in the range `[0..n]`, output `0;` followed by 10 more than the integer, in decimal. The decimal is the value to be converted to the appropriate base, and the `0;` represents the initial value of the conversion.

```
$
¶10
```

Append an extra base `10` to simplify the algorithm.

```
{
```

Reduce (right-to-left) over the list of numbers.

```
+`
```

Reduce (left-to-right) over the second last number.

```
\d+;(\d)(\d*¶(\d+))$
$.(*$3*_$1*);$2
```

Multiply the result so far (implicitly the first number in the match) by the base (`$3`) and add the next digit of the second last number (`$1`).

```
;¶.+$
```

Delete the base.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Port of [Jonathan's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209269/58974).

```
AôU ÔrÏììX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QfRVINRyz%2bzsWA&input=OA)

```
AôU ÔrÏììX     :Implicit input of integer U
A              :10
 ôU            :Range [A,A+U]
    Ô          :Reverse
     r         :Reduce
      Ï        :X=current total (initially first element) Y=current element (initially the second)
       ì       :Convert Y to base-10 digit array
        ìX     :Convert from base-X digit array
```